# Symfony including javascript in one environment but not another,

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've got a really basic symfony site and I'm trying to display an OpenLayers map.

I've included the required javascript files in my view.yml file.

```
indexSuccess:
  javascripts: [OpenLayers.js, http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js, http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js]

editSuccess:
  stylesheets: [form.css]

showSuccess:
  stylesheets: [show.css]
```

But my javascript files are only included when I access the site using the frontend_dev.php environment.

Also something in the dev environment is also including a CSS file which is 404ing. It's not included in the production environment and I'm not sure where it's coming from. It's a relative URI pointing to /js/theme/default/style.css. Although it might be something that the javascript is creating.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: have you cleared your cache and tried the non-dev environment? `symfony cc`

Comment: @richsage, clearing the cache fixed it. Put that as the answer and I'll accept you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make changes to configuration files such as `view.yml`, running in dev mode automatically uses the latest version of your file.  Running in production mode (or essentially, a non-dev mode) does not, and will use the compiled version from the cache.  Simply run:

```
symfony cc
```

to clear the cache and subsequently use the latest version of the files for your non-dev mode.